# Scrapy encoding data wrong

Tags: python, scrapy, encode

For some reason, when I grab a text value from a element using Scrapy, it display correctly, but when I put it in an array, it gets encoded improperly.

Here is the test: I used the word `Château`. In one case **test**, scrapy gets word then prints and adds it to an array. In the second case **test2**, I literally copy paste the word that was printed from another test into the array.

Here is my Scrapy python script:

```
value=node.xpath('//AddrDisplayMemberSerialization/text()').extract_first()
print value;
array={'test':value,'test2':'Château'}
print array
```

Automatically, the array encodes the values. Does python do this automatically or does Scrapy do this?

[image]

And why do they get encoded differently?

Comment: Yes. Python does it automaticaly. In Python3 Unicode string will be looking correct

Comment: @marni So in Python 3 it will all be correct?

Comment: Yes. But in Py2 it also correct(short: just view is difference, long: Python 2 and 3 work with Unicode in a different way), don't worry about it

Comment: True, but when I use the variable for lets say 'urlencode' to pass data, I get a question mark from the result. But I understand now! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens because of difference between Python2 and Python3. If you do this in Python3 it would work straight away

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:44:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> value = 'Château'
>>> print (value)
Château
>>> array={'test':value,'test2':'Château'}
>>> print(array)
{'test': 'Château', 'test2': 'Château'}
>>>
```

Now let's get back to Python2

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 18 2017, 09:17:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> value = 'Château'
>>> print value;
Château
>>> array={'test':value,'test2':'Château'}
>>> print array
{'test': 'Ch\xc3\xa2teau', 'test2': 'Ch\xc3\xa2teau'}
```

This happens because when you print array, it is converting to string representation and not unicode in python

```
>>> str(array)
"{'test': 'Ch\\xc3\\xa2teau', 'test2': 'Ch\\xc3\\xa2teau'}"
>>> print str(array)
{'test': 'Ch\xc3\xa2teau', 'test2': 'Ch\xc3\xa2teau'}
```

What you want to do while printing is do unicode escape

```
>>> print str(array).decode("unicode-escape")
{'test': 'ChÃ¢teau', 'test2': 'ChÃ¢teau'}
```

But wait this messes up the print? That is because of the encoding needed to print these character. Latin in short

```
>>> print str(array).decode("unicode-escape").encode("latin-1")
{'test': 'Château', 'test2': 'Château'}
```

Just upgrade to python3 and your issues would be sorted. But you would need to change your print statements to `print(...)`. Or else workout the encodings using code as I showed

Answer (score 1):

That's how it will be shown in Terminal.

But if you want it to show in utf-8 just do this in `settings.py`

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

Comment: @MaciekSemik As I told you data will not be shown as UTF-8 in terminal, but if you do `scrapy crawl spider_name -o output.json` you will get correct encoding

Comment: I have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: And when I use Ch\xe2teau and output it, I get a ?